# How to determine number of voices in one recorded file in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, voice-recognition

I want to extract the information such as how many voices as per person in one recorded file.

I know the NSSpeechRecognizer class to recognise the speech, but not able to get to know the number of voices in one recorded file.

Please provide some suggestion.

Thanks,
Yogesh Arora

Answer (score 0):

Counting the number of voices requires segmenting the audio file and diarising the speakers, which is by no means a simple task. Cocoa doesn't provide an API for that, at least yet. There are some open-source libraries that might help. You might want to check the [ALIZE toolkit](http://alize.univ-avignon.fr/index_en.html), for example.